# find the value of $p$ for which $S$ is convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

Given   $$ S= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(\log n) ^{\log n}} {n^p}$$

Then  S is convergent  if

choose the correct option

$1.$  $p>1$

$2.$ $ 0 <p <1$

$3.$ $p >0$

$4$. None  of these

My attempt : by leibtnizt test  option $1$, $3$ are  correct

Is its true ?

Comment: Is it $(\log n)^{\log n}$ or $\log(n^{\log n})$?

Comment: i have  edits its@angryavian

Comment: Option 2 is currently a subset of option 3, so if you believe 3 is correct, you believe 2 is correct.

Comment: ya  u  r correct @EricTowers that mean  answer is option $1,2,3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice 
$$  (\ln n)^{\ln n} = \left( \mathrm{e}^{\ln\ln n} \right)^{\ln n} = \left( \mathrm{e}^{\ln n} \right)^{\ln\ln n} = n^{\ln\ln n}  \text{.}  $$
For a sum to converge, we require $n \rightarrow \infty$ implies 
$$  \left| \frac{(-1)^n n^{\ln\ln n}}{n^p} \right| = \frac{n^{\ln\ln n}}{n^p} \rightarrow 0  \text{.}  $$
For any constant $p$, $\ln\ln n$ is eventually greater than $p$, so the summand magnitudes do not approach zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  Therefore, this sum diverges for all $p$.